# Calculate delivery date based on order date without weekends

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am trying to find a solution for the calculating the delivery date based on the order date (deliverydate equals with 3 days after the orderdate). However, need to take consideration the weekends.

```
<order>
   <orderdate>30/11/2016</orderdate>
</order>
```

Hence the delivery date must be **05/12/2016**.

Does anyone provide any help on this matter?

Any help is always appreciated!

Comment: Please explain in detail what "*need to take consideration the weekends*" means.

Comment: you need to calculate the delivery date excluding the weekends. for example if the order date is on 02/12/2016(Friday) then the delivery date has to be after 3 working days which will be on 07/12/2016(Wednesday)

Comment: You keep giving me examples, instead of explaining the rules. I don't even know which days are weekend in your business.

Comment: Saturday and Sunday are weekend days

Comment: 1. Weekends are not included in the calculation of the delivery date 2. need do be always 3 working days after the order date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Adding N work/business days to a date in pure XSLT 1.0

I have hesitated whether to calculate the target date, or use recursion. In the end, I have decided to use recursion, because that's the only way to consider holidays, too.

**Input XML**

```
<orders>
    <order>
        <order-date>2016-11-21</order-date>
    </order>
    <order>
        <order-date>2016-11-22</order-date>
    </order>
    <order>
        <order-date>2016-11-23</order-date>
    </order>
    <order>
        <order-date>2016-11-24</order-date>
    </order>
    <order>
        <order-date>2016-11-25</order-date>
    </order>
    <order>
        <order-date>2016-11-26</order-date>
    </order>
    <order>
        <order-date>2016-11-27</order-date>
    </order>
</orders>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="order">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="order-date"/>
        <delivery-date>
            <xsl:call-template name="add-work-days">
                <xsl:with-param name="start-JDN">
                    <xsl:call-template name="JDN">
                        <xsl:with-param name="date" select="order-date" />
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:with-param>
                <xsl:with-param name="add-days" select="3" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </delivery-date>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template name="add-work-days">
    <xsl:param name="start-JDN"/>
    <xsl:param name="add-days"/>

    <xsl:variable name="day-of-week" select="$start-JDN mod 7"/>
    <!--  Monday = 0 ... Saturday = 5, Sunday = 6 -->
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$day-of-week >= 5">
            <xsl:call-template name="add-work-days">
                <xsl:with-param name="start-JDN" select="$start-JDN + 1" />
                <xsl:with-param name="add-days" select="$add-days" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$add-days > 0">
            <xsl:call-template name="add-work-days">
                <xsl:with-param name="start-JDN" select="$start-JDN + 1" />
                <xsl:with-param name="add-days" select="$add-days - 1" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:call-template name="GD">
                <xsl:with-param name="JDN" select="$start-JDN" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template name="JDN">
    <xsl:param name="date"/>
    <xsl:variable name="year" select="substring($date, 1, 4)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="month" select="substring($date, 6, 2)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="day" select="substring($date, 9, 2)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="a" select="floor((14 - $month) div 12)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="y" select="$year + 4800 - $a"/>
    <xsl:variable name="m" select="$month + 12*$a - 3"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$day + floor((153*$m + 2) div 5) + 365*$y + floor($y div 4) - floor($y div 100) + floor($y div 400) - 32045" />
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template name="GD">
    <xsl:param name="JDN"/>
    <xsl:variable name="f" select="$JDN + 1401 + floor((floor((4 * $JDN + 274277) div 146097) * 3) div 4) - 38"/>
    <xsl:variable name="e" select="4*$f + 3"/>
    <xsl:variable name="g" select="floor(($e mod 1461) div 4)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="h" select="5*$g + 2"/>
    <xsl:variable name="D" select="floor(($h mod 153) div 5 ) + 1"/>
    <xsl:variable name="M" select="(floor($h div 153) + 2) mod 12 + 1"/>
    <xsl:variable name="Y" select="floor($e div 1461) - 4716 + floor((14 - $M) div 12)"/>

    <xsl:value-of select="$Y" />    
    <xsl:value-of select="format-number($M, '-00')"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="format-number($D, '-00')"/>
</xsl:template>     

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<orders>
   <order>
      <order-date>2016-11-21</order-date>
      <delivery-date>2016-11-24</delivery-date>
   </order>
   <order>
      <order-date>2016-11-22</order-date>
      <delivery-date>2016-11-25</delivery-date>
   </order>
   <order>
      <order-date>2016-11-23</order-date>
      <delivery-date>2016-11-28</delivery-date>
   </order>
   <order>
      <order-date>2016-11-24</order-date>
      <delivery-date>2016-11-29</delivery-date>
   </order>
   <order>
      <order-date>2016-11-25</order-date>
      <delivery-date>2016-11-30</delivery-date>
   </order>
   <order>
      <order-date>2016-11-26</order-date>
      <delivery-date>2016-12-01</delivery-date>
   </order>
   <order>
      <order-date>2016-11-27</order-date>
      <delivery-date>2016-12-01</delivery-date>
   </order>
</orders>
```

---

**Note**:

To make this useful generally, I have used the standard YYYY-MM-DD date format for both input and output. If your input uses another format, you will have to adjust the beginning of the `JDN` template so that it extracts the date components correctly. If you want the output to use another format, you will need to modify the end of the `GD` template so that it assembles the final date in the required order.

Comment: For example `<order-date>2016-02-28</order-date><delivery-date>2016-03-02</delivery-date>` as 2016 is a leap year with 29 days

Comment: @kokos Why don't you try it and see for yourself.

Comment: I have tried it and its calculate <delivery-date>2016-03-03</delivery-date>

Comment: 2016-02-28 is a Sunday, so the count only begins on Monday and the result is the following Thursday. You will see the same thing if you start on Sunday 2016-11-27: the result will be Thursday, 2016-12-01. This has nothing to do with leap years.